# Use .jar with referenced file paths in other project

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, path, filepath

I have **2 Java projects**, one is a **Web Project** in **NetBeans** and the other is a **Java Project** in **Eclipse**.

Just to know, the **Java Project** from **Eclipse** is used by the **Web Project** in **NetBeans** as a library **(.jar)**

---

### Situation:

**1. Java Project** from **Eclipse** has the following structure:

[image]

And inside the `src`, there is a `class` that uses the **file1**, **file2**, etc in some method using global variables like this:

```
public static final String PATH_ONE = "./files/file1.xml";
public static final String PATH_TWO = "./files/file2.xml";
...
```

Finally, when I test the method in some `main()` class everything works good.

---

**2. Web Project** from **NetBeans** has a `jar` reference to the above `library` and If everything works good, then the web project will be able to execute the `method` that uses the global variables without problems from the `library` project.

---

### Problem:

When I run the web project and I want to invoke the `method` from my `library` that uses the above `xml` files from it, for some reason, **NetBeans** or the **project** *(I don't certainly know)* looks for the path and fails in `Exception` because the path can not be found (It seems that tries to find the path in the web project and not in the `library` one).

**How can I solve this issue?** It sounds simple but I don't want to change my structure, load them as a resource or transfer files from one project to another and use external paths to make this work because I just make a recreation of the situation but I am working with lots of files with different folders and paths too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you unzip your jar you can't find your **folder** file because not is included in your classpath.

You can See **.classpath** file and the folder isn't. For these reason is FileNotFoudnException.

You can to add how source folder in Eclipse ID:

1. **Right click in your project/Build Path/ New  source folder**

Create the source folder . Then you can add a new package with the name Folder.

Your project:

- src
- resources

  - folder

    resource1.xml

    resource2.xml

2. Modify your java project.

public static final String PATH ="**/folder/resource1.xml**";

Now, if you try to unzip the jar, you can see that the folder was added in the .classpath.

It works for me. I tried to paste image but i'm new user.